# How to use COUNTIFS VBA Function to count value between two dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use VBA to count the number of times a value occurred between two given dates. The output should display 1.

I am using the following code but cant seem to get the correct value.

```
Sub clientIntAnalysis()
Dim r As Integer
Dim startdate As Date, endDate As Date
startdate = "07/01/2019"
endDate = "07/30/2019"
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, rng As Range, rng2 As Range

    LastRow = Sheet3.Range("M" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Sheet3.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With Sheet3
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 14), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(8, 13), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    End With

    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & startdate, rng, "<=" & endDate, rng, "=" & "Client Interested") 'q3

    MsgBox r


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is your `CountIfs` function working on spreadsheet ? Can you try that.

Comment: @Mikku it is, here is the formula version, `=COUNTIFS(clientmenu!$M$8:$N$8,">="&"07/01/2019",clientmenu!$M$8:$N$8,"<="&"07/30/2019",clientmenu!$N$8:$O$8,"Client Interested")` produces **1**

Comment: You are using wrong Range in your Code for `Client Interested` , should be `rng2`

Comment: Also, even in your spreadsheet formula, you are comparing only 2 cells `8 to 8` see the ranges, you will know

Comment: @Mikku i have `LastRow`and `LastCol` declared to adjust accordingly when I add new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this code (Untested)**

Now your ranges are as per you said in comment:

```
Sub clientIntAnalysis()

Dim r As Integer
Dim startdate As Date, endDate As Date
startdate = "07/01/2019"
endDate = "07/30/2019"


    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, rng As Range, rng2 As Range

    LastRow = Sheet3.Range("M" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'LastCol = Sheet3.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With Sheet3
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 13), .Cells(LastRow, 14))
        Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(8, 14), .Cells(LastRow, 15))
    End With

    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & startdate, rng, "<=" & endDate, rng2, "=" & "Client Interested") 'q32

    MsgBox r


End Sub
```

Comment:`=COUNTIFS(clientmenu!$M$8:$N$8,">="&"07/01/2019",clientmenu!$M$8:$N$8,"<="&"07/30/2019",clientmenu!$N$8:$O$8,"Client Interested")`

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer as it does produce the output result i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of my code, looks like I had to increment the value of the last Column by 1.

```
Sub clientIntAnalysis()

Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, rng As Range, rang2 As Range, lastcol2 As Long, r as long

startdate = "07/01/2019"
enddate = "07/30/2019"
LastRow = Sheet3.Range("M" & Sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheet3.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastcol2 = Sheet3.Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

Set rang2 = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(8, 14), Sheet3.Cells(lastrow, lastcol2))
    With Sheet3
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, 13), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

r= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" & startdate, rng, "<=" & enddate, rang2, "Client Interested") 'q3

    MsgBox r


End Sub
```